# Operators on Hilbert Space in Integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, positive-definite, positive-matrices

Theorem 1.5.8 in "Positive Definite Matrices" written by R. Bhatia is that the function $f(A)=A^r$ is convex on $L_+(\mathbb{H})$ for $1\leq r\leq 2$.

I'm struggling to understand some part of the proof : From the integral formula
$$ t^r = \int_0^\infty \frac{t^2}{\lambda+t} \;d\mu(\lambda) $$
the author conclude that for positive oprators $A$
$$ A^r = \int_0^\infty A^2(\lambda +A)^{-1} \;d\mu(\lambda). $$

However, I'm not familiar with forms like this; integrad contains operators.

My attempt to understand this is considering the spectral measure $E_A$ of $A$. From
$A^r = \int t^r\; dE_A$, we have
$$ A^r = \int t^r\;dE_A(t) = \int \int_0^\infty \frac{t^2}{\lambda+t}\; d\mu(\lambda)dE_A(t). $$
But I don't know the Fubini theorem holds for this case, i.e.,
$$  \int_0^\infty \int \frac{t^2}{\lambda+t}\; dE_A(t)d\mu(\lambda) = \int \int_0^\infty \frac{t^2}{\lambda+t}\; d\mu(\lambda)dE_A(t). $$
How can I understand this?

Comment: I guess the measure $\mu$ depends on $r.$ Your approach with spectral measure is inconvenient as different positive operators have different spectral measures.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I also think this approach is not a promising way to understand this. Then is there any idea for understanding this?

Comment: I think I have misunderstood your problem. If you want to use the spectral theorem to justify the integral formula representing $A^r$ then applying the spectral theorem is useful. You can apply $$\langle Av,v\rangle =\int\limits_0^\infty \langle A^2(A+\lambda I)^{-1}v,v\rangle d\mu(\lambda)$$ Then you are down to the standard Fubini theorem when expressing the inner product by the integral with the spectral measure. By the way what is  the formula for $\mu$ ? It should depend on the exponent $r.$

Comment: Oh, I see. I will reconsider it again based on your comment. Thank you. The measure $\mu$ is given by $$ d\mu(\lambda) = \frac{\sin r\pi}{\pi} \lambda^{r-1}\;d\lambda $$ where $d\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Thus it depends on $r$.